# Text when UITextField is first responder is either being clipped or appearing at bottom of content view despite vertical alignment being set to center

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uitextfield

I am experiencing the following issue, which may or may not be a Xamarin.iOS issue (it may be an iOS issue).

A UIViewController has the following:

- I have a UITableView which has a number of UITableViewCell
  prototypes.
- One of the UITableViewCell prototypes contains a UITextField.
- The UITextField auto layout constraints have the trailing and leading
  space set to 20, a fixed height of 41 pixels and bottom space to
  superview set to 0. The content vertical alignment is set to centre.
- The UITextField font is Helvetica Neue 14.0px and the border style is
  set to none.

The problem is that sometimes, generally after some other view controllers have been shown, is that when a text field is being edited the characters when typing are aligned to the bottom of the content area. When the text field resigns first responder status the text jumps back to centre  vertical alignment. See the attached screenshots showing a UITextField when it is first responder and after it has resigned first responder status. (Borders, etc are being used to help diagnose the issue)

[image: when UITextField is first responder]

[image: After first responder status has been resigned]

If the text fields height is set to the default then the text flashes as characters are entered - as though the text is being drawn below the visible area and being clipped.

If you are aware of an issues with Xamarin.iOS which may cause this, or have come across this problem before, I would be grateful for any help you could provide.

Comment: You could always shrink the UITextField, or increase the FontSize inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Set clips to bounds equal to false to solve this issue.